# Firebase Chat messages not ordering correctly

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have just completed this basic chat app based on a tutorial on YouTube. NO user name needed for using it. But my messages are not ordering correctly. It is sorting as auto generated ID on FireStore. There are total two field in Firebase "message" collection that I have created

1. "username" {this user name randomly generated by FireBase as user ID. example: 1Mrayhz7EKL7MklHXUxv}
2. "messagetext"

I don't understanding what should I do now

//Here's the code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController messaingTextBox = TextEditingController();

  final CollectionReference cr =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    body:
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: cr.snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

              return ListView.builder(
                reverse: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                      .data()['username'],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10,
                            ),
                            Container(
                              // width: 38.0,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.6,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                          .data()['messagetext'],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  cursorColor: HexColor("#003F51"),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  controller: messaingTextBox,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Message m = Message(
                    username: "unkown ",
                    messagetext: messaingTextBox.text.toString());

                cr.add(m.mapMessages());
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.send),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Message {
  final String username;
  final String messagetext;

  Message({this.messagetext, this.username});

  mapMessages() {
    return {'messagetext': messagetext, 'username': username};
  }
}
```

Please help me for solving this isue

Answer (score 2):

You need to add third field to store time.
Then in the code try to add `orderBy` operator.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages')
    .orderBy('time_field', descending: true);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple just add a timestamp with each message lets say `createdAt`, and the  use

**NOTE**: The type of `createdAt` must be Date

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('messages').orderBy('createdAt', descending: true)
```